# input forced to focus while onblur event

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have try to focus while onblur Event. it works on chrome not on firefox. how to sort out.

```
function a() {
    $("#login").focus();
}
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#login").focus();
});
```

```html
<input id="login" onblur="a()"></input>
```

Please help.

Comment: Why don't you fiddle this code?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8141239/issues-with-using-onblur-event _It turns out that IE and FireFox have very different behavior when it comes to onBlur._

Comment: What is the point of this code? To make sure that `input` element never loses focus?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just remove the `onblur` function and write instead:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#login").focus();

    $(document).on('click', function () {
        $("#login").focus();
    });
});
```

Live jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ysjkzvh7/

Answer (score 1):

Do something like that;

```
$( "#login" ).blur(function() {
  $(this).focus();
});
```

and

```
<input id="login"></input>
```

just try different things. But every browser is different.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want the input to lose focus, just unbind the blur function from it.

Try this -

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#login").unbind('blur');
});
```